# signIn with NextAuth Credentials does not return username to session

Tags: authentication, session, next.js, credentials, next-auth

I'm using NextAuth Credentials provider to handle authentication to my app, I have been following this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0eu4_lLFkGk&t=2026s.

After successfully signing in with the user, I tried to access the user info in the session but it just returned an empty object.
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/RqAgC.png)

How can I save the user info to the session, I have been doing exactly like the tutorial.

Here is the code of the NextAuth handler and the login api route that I used

```
const handler = NextAuth({
    providers: [
        CredentialsProvider({
            credentials: {
                username: { label: "Username", type: "text" },
                password: { label: "Password", type: "password" }
            },
            async authorize(credentials) {
              const res = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/login", {
                  method: "POST",
                  headers: {
                      "Content-Type": "application/json"
                  },
                  body: JSON.stringify({
                      username: credentials?.username, 
                      password: credentials?.password
                  }),
              })

              const user = await res.json();

              if (user) {
                  // Any object returned will be saved in `user` property of the JWT
                  return user
              } else {
                  // If you return null then an error will be displayed advising the user to check their details.
                  return null

              }
            }
        }),
})

export { handler as GET, handler as POST }
```

Here is the login api POST method

```
interface RequestBody {
    username: string,
    password: string
}

export async function POST(request: Request){
    const body: RequestBody = await request.json();
    
    const admin = await prisma.admin.findFirst({
        where: {
            username: body.username
        }
    })

    if (admin && (await bcrypt.compare(body.password, admin.password))) {
        const { password, ...adminWithoutPass } = admin;
        return new Response(JSON.stringify(adminWithoutPass));
    }
    else return new Response(JSON.stringify(null));
}
```

I tried using the Insomnia request response checking tool and it successfully returned the user object.

Answer (score 0):

To do so you have to use the `session` and `jwt` [callbacks](https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/options#callbacks) to your next-auth file:

```js
async jwt({ token, user}) {
  if(user){
     token.user = user;
  }
  return token;
}

async session({ session, token, user }) {
  session.user = token.user;
  return session
},
```

if you want to see the content of your session you have to call `useSession` hook from you client component:

```js
import { useSession } from "next-auth/react";

const MyComponent = () => {
 const session = useSession();
 console.log(session);
//...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for responding!

I tried using your code in the callback option, but got a type mismatch, here is the error https://imgur.com/a/dBACD9K

So I tried to work around it by changing the code to the image below, well, it still did not work and the session still returned an empty object :((. Do you know what went wrong?

Comment: @QuốcHuyNguyễn how do u access the session to log it?

Comment: @QuốcHuyNguyễn have a look I updated my answer

Comment: I wanted to display the username on the navbar, here's my navbar component: https://imgur.com/a/W2Cdiwi. It does not output any user, I also used the test function to check the session variable

Comment: @QuốcHuyNguyễn in your example you are destructing `data` from `useSession` and `session` is just the type so you have to use `data.user` not `session.user` and user data should be there

Comment: I tried assigning session = useSession() and logged it to console, I still got an empty user object :(( https://imgur.com/a/R7VwAAz

Comment: are u sure that the `authorize` function is returnng the expected data? also try to console.log(user) from inside the jwt callback

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254387/discussion-between-quc-huy-nguyn-and-hatana).